# Email to CSV C# - String isn't formatting correctly

Tags: c#, csv, stringbuilder

So I am currently parsing emails that we receive from work, all of which are formatted almost exactly the same, and I am getting the data that I need out of all of them, however I am experiencing problems retrieving a "description", which comes in multiple lines. I've tried removing the "\n" out of these strings, but it doesn't always work. When I open the .csv files, the formatting is fine sometimes, but otherwise these extra returns in the strings ruin the entire thing.

Here is my code:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        helper();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit ... ");
        Console.ReadKey();

    } //end main method

    public static void helper()
    {
        //initiate outlook
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem item = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder subFolder = null;

        try
        {
            app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            ns.Logon(null, null, false, false);

            inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            subFolder = inboxFolder.Folders["WorkOrders"]; //folder.Folders[1];
            Console.WriteLine("Folder Name: {0}", subFolder.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of Emails: {0}", subFolder.Items.Count.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine();

            //Variables for loop
            String sub;
            String date;
            String time;
            String body;
            String desc;
            String storeNumber;
            String workOrderNumber;
            int indexOfDesc;
            int indexOfSp;
            int items = subFolder.Items.Count;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Work Order Number");
            dt.Columns.Add("Date");
            dt.Columns.Add("Store Number");
            dt.Columns.Add("Description");
            dt.Rows.Add("Work Order Number", "Date", "Store Number", "Description");
            dt.Rows.Add("", "", "", ""); // just a blank row

            for (int i = 1; i <= items; i++)
            {
                item = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)subFolder.Items[i];
                sub = item.Subject;
                date = item.SentOn.ToLongDateString();
                body = item.Body;
                desc = "";
                storeNumber = sub.Substring(0, 5);
                workOrderNumber = sub.Substring(sub.Length - 10);
                indexOfDesc = body.IndexOf("Description Overview:");
                indexOfSp = body.IndexOf("Safety Precautions:");
                desc = body.Substring(indexOfDesc, indexOfSp - indexOfDesc);
                desc = desc.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
                desc = desc.Replace("\n", string.Empty);

                // Add row in data table
                dt.Rows.Add(workOrderNumber, date, storeNumber, desc);

                // Process Date
                createCSV(dt);

                // *** Console Output for testing *** //
                Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}", i.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Store Number: {0}", sub.Substring(0, 5));
                Console.WriteLine("Work Order Number: # " + workOrderNumber);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", date);
                Console.WriteLine(desc);
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            PrintTable(dt);
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            ns = null;
            app = null;
            inboxFolder = null;
        } //end finally

    }

    private static void PrintTable(DataTable dt)
    {
        DataTableReader dtReader = dt.CreateDataReader();
        while (dtReader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0} = {1} ",
                    dtReader.GetName(i).Trim(),
                    dtReader.GetValue(i).ToString().Trim());
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        dtReader.Close();
    }

    /**
     * createCSV(DataTable dt) takes each line from data 
     * table and appends it to a csv file created at the var path
     * @param dt - DataTable 
     **/
    public static void createCSV(DataTable dt)
    {
        String path = "C:\\Users\\WORK\\Desktop\\test.csv";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows){
            foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns){
                sb.Append(FormatCSV(dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString()) + ",");
            } // end foreach
            sb.Remove(sb.Length-1,1); //remove comma
            sb.AppendLine();
        } // end foreach
        File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
    } // end createCSV()

    public static string FormatCSV(string input)
    {
        try
        {
            if (input == null)
                return string.Empty;

            bool containsQuote = false;
            bool containsComma = false;
            int len = input.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < len && (containsComma == false || containsQuote == false); i++)
            {
                char ch = input[i];
                if (ch == '"')
                    containsQuote = true;
                else if (ch == ',')
                    containsComma = true;
            }

            if (containsQuote && containsComma)
                input = input.Replace("\"", "\"\"");

            if (containsComma)
                return "\"" + input + "\"";
            else
                return input;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

} //end class
```

And here is a screenshot of what the CSV file looks like. Mind you, all of the descriptions in the email have extra spaces and stuff in them, and I highlighted the rows that worked the way I want them too: no extra spaces, just one line of the proper information. You can see how the returns ruin the spreadsheet though. 
[image: Image of the CSV - file opened in excel]

So any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found it was always best to do replace with `\r\n`, `\r`, and `\n` in that order. In your case though, you are just replacing with an empty string -- perhaps just also do the `\r` replace.

Comment: Worked perfectly! add your comment to the answer so I can update it. I replaced "\r\n" with empty, then replaced \r and finally \n and it worked. Thank you so much @TyCobb

Answer (score 0):

One problem when working with newlines is that sometimes it's not the standard CRLF (`\r\n`) that Windows uses. Sometimes it is just `\r` and sometimes it is just `\n`.

When you don't have control over the newline character it can be a decent safety net to replace all three.

```
var sub = string.Empty;
var foo = myString.Replace("\r\n", sub).Replace("\r", sub).Replace("\n", sub);
```

This fixes those cases where you are getting say

`Some line item\r\n
Another line item\n
Last line item\r`

Removing just `\n` may work just fine in one application, but another application displaying the same string may still put it on a new line.